# Web scraping from a Json page but HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the data from this website.
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
However, I keep getting errors when I execute the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener

url = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&page='
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'}
request_interval = 2  # interval

urls = []
df = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 2):
        url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, '&page='+str(i)+'&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken')
        urls.append(str(url))

    for url in urls:
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
        request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
        result = json.loads(html.decode('utf-8'))['blockNumber']
        df.extend(json.loads(html.decode('utf-8'))['blockNumber'])
        print('Completed URL : ', url)

pdf = pd.DataFrame(df)

pdf.to_csv("output.csv")
```

I have tried several solutions I found here Stackoverflow.
[urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375665/urllib2-httperror-http-error-400-bad-request-python)
[urllib2 HTTP Error 400: Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840303/urllib2-http-error-400-bad-request)

I also have changed

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
```

and

```
{'Authorization': auth,
             'Content-Type':'application/json',
             'Accept':'application/json'}
```

but still getting the same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urljoin` is for different purpose than what you are intending to use.

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)

> Construct a full (“absolute”) URL by combining a “base URL” (base) with another URL (url). Informally, this uses components of the base URL, in particular the addressing scheme, the network location and (part of) the path, to provide missing components in the relative URL. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
> >>> urljoin('http://www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/Python.html', 'FAQ.html')
> 'http://www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/FAQ.html'
> ```

I am not sure if you can use it for combining query params of an url

with this the url you would get after the urljoin would be something like

```
https://api.etherscan.io/&page=1&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

which is wrong.

use string concatenation.  in the first for loop, change from

```
url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, '&page='+str(i)+'&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken')
```

to

```
url = url + str(i) + '&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken'
```

you are reassigning your value to the main `url` variable, inside the for loop.
so in the next iteration you will be adding the offset part on to the first iterations url.

adding on with the above change, instead of

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, '&page='+str(i)+'&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken')
    urls.append(str(url))
```

you could do

```
for i in range(1, 2):
        urls.append(url + str(i) + '&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken')
```

hope you are aware that the first loop will run only once. `range(1,2)` will return `[1]` and not `[1, 2]`